# Get exported singleton instance from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an `ExampleView` class which should be singleton. Inside this class I have method `render` which I would like to call from another js file via object name 'ExampleView'.
Here is the code:

```
import View from './view';

class ExampleView extends View {
    render() {
        return `<span>Test</span>`;
    }
}
export default new ExampleView(); //<- exporting as singleton and this object I try to get via it's name
```

First I should do is retrieve somehow exported singleton object `ExampleView` from name 'ExampleView' and then call method `render`.

```
class Test {
    getInstanceOfModuleByName(name) {
        //window[name].render();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot find any way to get `ExampleView` instance from name, but my `ExampleView` class needs to be a singleton.

I know I can do this in following way and then call it by `window['ExampleView'].render()`:

```
ExampleView = {
    render: function() {
        return `<span>Test</span>`;
    }
}
```

But I really need to implement it with modulable ES6.

Can you explain me what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populating global scope is not the ES6 way. I think you can do it like this to your `export`

```
//
// Class definition
//
window.ExampleView = new ExampleView();

export default window.ExampleView;
```

Comment: This is acceptable solution because creating an object reference in window allows to get this instance later via string. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. But I don't encourage this method. This is just for yor special use case.

Comment: Probably I move this object reference to my dedicated global object instead using window. Why you don't encourage this method? Is this a bad idea? Could you provide solution you will implement according to my problem?

Comment: As I told you, for your requirement, this could be only solution. Populating global scope is not something I would like to do when we are building things in an Object oriented way and that's exactly why there is module architecture in place. You could simply import same instance of class in different files. I wouldn't have architectured my app to call modules by name in first place. There could be some other solution to what you are trying to do. Why do you want to call modules by name?

Answer (score 0):

You just import the instance

```
import whateverYouWantToCallYourViewInstance from './ExampleView'

// snip

return whateverYouWantToCallYourViewInstance.render();
```

It will be the same object.

---

Worth noting: Singletons are evil. Using the ES module system to pass instances around is a bit of abuse.